# Python re-setting the for loop if an element is deleted in an iteration

Tags: python, loops

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
for x in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[x] == 'c':
        list1.pop(x)
```

The above code is an idea to explain the task what Iam performing. I have a list that Iam looping through when it finds something or meet some condition it will delete that specific index element accordingly.

For instance if it finds element 'c' in the list then it will delete it from the list but it throws an `IndexError: list index out of range` . I need help to get an idea that can i re-set my loop so that it will loop through the next element without any error for instance once it pass through a, b it will find c and delete then without `IndexError` it should go and check remaining elements 'd' and 'e'.

if the loop deletes any element it should check the next iteration without error, any suggestions that i can try?

Comment: Use a `while` loop with index counter. If you don't delete an element you increase the counter by 1, if you delete something then you don't increase the counter.

Comment: print([ch for ch in list1 if ch != 'c'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may enjoy the `filter` function.

```py
def myCondition(x):
  return x == 'a'

list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
list1 = list(filter(myCondition, list1))
```

Note that `myCondition` retains those "True" elements, so if you want to delete them, you need to flip the condition. This has a slight overhead since it's creating a new Iterable, but I don't think it matters in this specific scenario.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_filter.asp

Answer (score 1):

Check below code :  list comprehension

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
list1 = [ i for i in list1 if i != 'c']
list1
```

Output:

[image]